# How to implement sorted Multivalue Tree map which always returns non null value

Tags: java, collections, guava, apache-commons, treemap

For reasons of Struts I need a Sorted map which always returns non null value.

For my concrete case I have following implementation and **it works fine**:

```
public class NonEmptyMap extends TreeMap<String, List<MyObject>> {
    @Override
    public List<MyObject> get(Object key) {

        final List<MyObject> result = super.get(key);
        if (result == null) {
            super.put((String) key, new NonEmptyList<MyObject>(MyObject.class));
        }
        return super.get(key);
    }

}
```

`NonEmptyList` is a special version of list which always returns non null object. For example `nonEmptyList.get(2)` call for nonEmptyList of size 1 will be reason of creation 2 empty `MyObject` objects, inserting them into list and returning the latest element to the client call .

I would like to generalize implementation to support any `Key/Value`

Is there any ready library implementations ?

Answer (score 0):

Although I'm pretty sure your list implementation won't comply `List` contract (i.e. [`get()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#get(int)) should throw if *the index is out of range `(index < 0 || index >= size())`*, unless you're willing to return `MAX_INTEGER` from `size()`, but this can lead to other unexpected results...), you can use custom [`ListMultimap`](https://guava.dev/releases/28.2-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/ListMultimap.html) using [`Multimaps#newListMultimap(Map, Supplier<List>)`](https://guava.dev/releases/28.2-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Multimaps.html#newListMultimap-java.util.Map-com.google.common.base.Supplier-):

```
static <K extends Comparable<K>, V> ListMultimap<K, V> create(Class<V> valueClass) {
    return Multimaps.newListMultimap(new TreeMap<>(), () -> new NonEmptyList<>(valueClass));
}
```

Comment: It is correct but ListMultimap is not iterable and it is problem for me

Comment: Neither is TreeMap?

Comment: It is not a map at all https://guava.dev/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/ListMultimap.html

Comment: Yes, [`Multimap` is not a `Map`](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#multimap), but I was answering the concern that `ListMultimap` is not an iterable and said that neither is `TreeMap` (doesn't implement `Iterable`). If you want to use `Multimap` in a map-like way, use [`Multimap.asMap()` view](https://guava.dev/releases/28.2-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/ListMultimap.html#asMap--).

Comment: Part of the reason `Multimap` is not a `Map` is that your implementation in your question is an invalid `Map`: `get` is not supposed to modify the backing map by the contract of `Map`.